What does "Jealousy of someone" mean?
"Jealousy of someone". Does it mean?

"Someone's jealousy towards you" or 
"You are jealous of them"

I have two sentence. "We should understand the jealousy of God"
"Jealousy of siblings must not be appreciated"

Did you write those sentences, or find them somewhere? It depends on the context. "The jealousy of someone" could refer to an emotion they display, but if you are "jealous of someone" you envy something that they have.

@KateBunting i found them online.

The 'jealousy of God' is a well-known Biblical doctrine in Christianity.

@Micheal Harvey.Yes i was listening a video on it.I believe here 'Jealousy of God" is reffering to God's jealousy, am i right?

Note that with the definite article, "THE jealousy of [someone]," it's not a pattern we're likely to encounter in ordinary modern usage outside of this theological one. For a "belonging-to" meaning, we're a lot more likely to say "my sister's jealousy," and for an "object-of" meaning we're a lot more likely to use a possessive, saying who was jealous, rather than "the," or maybe use zero article as in your example.

Humans are not jealous of God. God is the one who's "jealous," a recurring theme. No one takes it literally that God is annoyed when I am taller or make more money or worship other gods. It's a concept that humans can grasp.

Of in the structure The X of Y can often be ambiguous in English, and will require a context to make clear what is meant. For example:

The jealousy of my sister reared its ugly head.

Without context this could mean:

My sister was jealous (maybe she wanted something belonging to me.).

or...

Someone was jealous of my sister (maybe she is beautiful and other girls are jealous of her at parties.)

The OP mentions the jealousy of God. Without going into detail (this is an English language site, not a theology site), there are important examples of this ambiguity in the Bible. For example, in the book of Romans the apostle Paul talks about the righteousness of God. Many books have been written about that expression: Does it mean the righteousness which God has in himself? Or does it mean the righteousness that I now have, and which by grace comes from God? Is it God's righteousness, or is it my righteousness received from God? All of which is about the meaning of the small possessive word of.
So the important point here is that as a reader, understand that there will be times when ambiguity exists. And as a writer, if clarity is important, provide the necessary context or rewrite the sentence.
EDIT.
As noted in the comment, the presence or absence of the definite article can itself be part of the context. The jealousy of children could have the meanings shown above, but jealousy of children tips the balance. It's more likely to mean jealousy that is directed towards the children, not jealousy that is possessed by the children.

It might be worth mentioning, since the OP gave an example with zero article, that this is more unambiguously about the object rather than source of jealousy ("jealousy of siblings").
